# Evaluating $\int_{p} f(p) \delta(p+a) \Theta(p)= f(-a) \Theta(-a)$ for Heaviside theta function

Tags: improper-integrals, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I want to evaluate the following integral

For given arbitrary function $f$ and Dirac Delta function $\delta$ with Heaviside Theta function $\Theta$, what is the form of

\begin{align}
\int_{p} f(p) \delta(p+a) \Theta(p) 
\end{align}

Mathematica just produces $f(-a) \Theta(-a)$ for some condition $a$. i.e. ,$a\in \mathbb{R}$.

It seems one can safely shift the input of the Heaviside Theta function via the Dirac Delta function. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [Guidelines for good use of $\rm\LaTeX$ in question titles](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct if $a\neq 0$. By definition of the Dirac delta $\delta_{-a}(x) = \delta(x+a)$, for any function $g$ continuous at $x=-a$
$$
\int_{\Bbb R} g(x)\,\delta_{-a}(\mathrm d x) = g(-a).
$$
In particular, if $f$ is continuous at $x=-a \neq 0$, then $g(x) = f(x)\,\Theta(x)$ is continuous and so
$$
\int_{\Bbb R} g(x)\,\delta_{-a}(\mathrm d x) = f(-a)\,\Theta(-a).
$$
In particular, if $a> 0$, $\int_{\Bbb R} g(x)\,\delta_{-a}(\mathrm d x) = 0$ and if $a<0$, $\int_{\Bbb R} g(x)\,\delta_{-a}(\mathrm d x) = f(-a)$.

If $a=0$, then it is unclear what the value of $\Theta(0)$ is ... and in general smooth approximation can bring different results, see also these related questions [What is the value of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^a \delta(x - a) dx$ and related integrals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4427947/what-is-the-value-of-the-integral-int-inftya-deltax-a-dx-and-relate/4427952#4427952) and this one [What is the integral of $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} H(t)\delta(t)dt$ ($H(t)$ Heaviside step, $\delta(t)$ Dirac delta)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2819917/what-is-the-integral-of-int-infty-infty-ht-deltatdt-ht-heavi/2820216#2820216)